# Unit testing : mocking a factory method using mockito or powermock

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have a class with the following structure

```
public class MyClass{
   private MyClass(){
   }

   public static MyClass getInstance(){
       return new MyClass();
   }

   //some instance method.
}
```

Using powermock I'm able to mock "MyClass" as follows.

```
PowerMock.mockStaticClass(Myclass.class);
```

But I'm unable to return any valid object when someone calls getInstance() on MyClass.
i.e., How dO I fill the following blank.

```
Mock.when(MyClass.getInstance()).thenReturn(<What do I return here>);
```

return value is needed because I need to stub/verify some instance methods.

Can someone help me figure out this?

Comment: Well what are you trying to do? You could create an instance of your real class, or you could create a mock. You say you're "unable to return any valid object" - what's stopping you?

Comment: I can't return an object because the constructor is private.

Comment: Ah, I see... but are you trying to return a mock? What happens if you try `PowerMock.mockClass`?

Comment: @Jon Skeet I have a doubt about the method you suggested. In the method that I'm testing I made a call to `MyClass.getInstace()` method and made _instance method calls_ from the object returned by `getInstance()`.In the test but I didn't stub `getInstance()`.I just stubbed instance methods. What happens when the method under test actually calls `MyClass.getInstance()`??

Comment: I wasn't suggesting *replacing* your `mockStaticClass` call - I was suggesting that the value you return from `thenReturn` should be the mock for the *instance* methods.

Comment: Oh!! I got your point... Thanks Jon.

Comment: Righto - will convert these comments into an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can mock the *instance* as well as the static method, and make the mocked static method return a reference to the mocked instance. Something like:

```
MyClass mock = PowerMock.mockClass(MyClass.class);

PowerMock.mockStaticClass(MyClass.class);
Mock.when(MyClass.getInstance()).thenReturn(mock);
```

(I've never used PowerMock, so the syntax may be slightly wrong...)